# KUDU giving forbidden error - 403 when trying to access deployed function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, adx

I am facing issue related to the forbidden error while trying to access it in kudu. I am facing the same error when trying to access over the browser .
Also , I tried to publish the function as zip package , I am getting error

```
Publish has encountered an error. The Publish URL https://adxiprocfuncria01euwprd.scm.azurewebsites.net/ is unreachable. The application may be stopped, restarting or unavailable. Try again once the publish target is available."
```

I tried to add my client IP in the allowed list but still I am facing the same issue .

Also , when I access without scm , I get app service is available message but whenI put scm , then I get forbidden error .
[image]

I also tried to download the published profile from portal and publish URL seems to be same .

Answer (score 1):

403 - This can mean many things; either you don't have access to this site, the site is stopped or the quota is exceeded.

- Are the developer of the web site? If yes Can you check whether your webapp has any [access restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#restrict-access-to-an-scm-site) added to access the kudu site ( under Networking --> Access Restrictions).If there are any try removing them.  If you are not the developer, just contact your administrator and allow your ip to access this website.
- If an [app exceeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor) the CPU (short), CPU (Day), or bandwidth quota, the app is stopped until the quota resets. During this time, all incoming requests result in an HTTP 403 error. If the app Memory quota is exceeded, the app is stopped temporarily. You can increase quota for your app by upgrading to higher app service plan.

Comment: With regards to your first point , I have added my public IP Address in the Access Restrictions part under Networking .With that also , I was facing the issue . Is there any other alternative which we can try ?

Comment: @AyushiGupta - I assume that newly added rule in access restriction has the less priority and it is given with the action as allow instaed of deny  even you are still not able to access the kudu console.

Comment: I have changed the priority to 129 and also I tried to change the access rule to allow and deny but still issue is same . Please let me know how can i further approach this issue .

Comment: @AyushiGupta - can you assign this new rule to least priority of all your existing rules and keep the action as allow instead of deny. and check it out

Comment: Thank you Venkatesh . I am able to access Azure app service browser by whitelisting all IP's in following way : 0.0.0.0/0 in Access restrictions .

Comment: But , I am facing issue when we are publishing as publish URL uses scm . Publish URL still shows IP forbidden due to which publishing the azure function from Visual studio is still failing .

Comment: @AyushiGupta I would suggest you to open a new thread/start a new discussion for this issue for better assistance and tracking.

Comment: Sure , I created a new one . Thanks Venkatesh .